# Need help figuring out why Fullcalendar isn't showing my events. - no errors showing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I am using Laravel 7. I followed the instructions from the Fullcalendar website and have searched for days trying to figure this out.

For some reason, I can't pull or save data. I've tried doing a die-dump and it's like the code isn't firing. Maybe someone can see something I'm missing. I am using the cdn's for ajax, jquery and fullcalendar.

Here is the code for the controller:

```
public function index()
{
    if(request()->ajax())
    {

        $start = (!empty($_GET["start"])) ? ($_GET["start"]) : ('');
        $end = (!empty($_GET["end"])) ? ($_GET["end"]) : ('');

        $data = Event::whereDate('start', '>=', $start)->whereDate('end',   '<=', $end)->get(['id','title','start', 'end']);
        return Response::json($data);
    }
    return view('calender');
}


public function create(Request $request)
{
    $insertArr = [ 'title' => $request->title,
        'start' => $request->start,
        'end' => $request->end
    ];
    $event = Event::insert($insertArr);
    return Response::json($event);
}


public function update(Request $request)
{
    $where = array('id' => $request->id);
    $updateArr = ['title' => $request->title,'start' => $request->start, 'end' => $request->end];
    $event  = Event::where($where)->update($updateArr);

    return Response::json($event);
}


public function destroy(Request $request)
{
    $event = Event::where('id',$request->id)->delete();

    return Response::json($event);
}
```

Here is the script from the view:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var SITEURL = "{{url('/')}}";
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        editable: true,
        events: SITEURL + "calendar",
        displayEventTime: true,
        editable: true,
        eventRender: function (event, element, view) {
            if (event.allDay === 'true') {
                event.allDay = true;
            } else {
                event.allDay = false;
            }
        },
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        select: function (start, end, allDay) {
            var title = prompt('Event Title:');

            if (title) {
                var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
                var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");

                $.ajax({
                    url: SITEURL + "calendar/create",
                    data: 'title=' + title + '&amp;start=' + start + '&amp;end=' + end,
                    type: "POST",
                    success: function (data) {
                        displayMessage("Added Successfully");
                    }
                });
                calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                    {
                        title: title,
                        start: start,
                        end: end,
                        allDay: allDay
                    },
                    true
                );
            }
            calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
        },

        eventDrop: function (event, delta) {
            var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
            var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
            $.ajax({
                url: SITEURL + 'calendar/update',
                data: 'title=' + event.title + '&amp;start=' + start + '&amp;end=' + end + '&amp;id=' + event.id,
                type: "POST",
                success: function (response) {
                    displayMessage("Updated Successfully");
                }
            });
        },
        eventClick: function (event) {
            var deleteMsg = confirm("Do you really want to delete?");
            if (deleteMsg) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: SITEURL + 'calendar/delete',
                    data: "&amp;id=" + event.id,
                    success: function (response) {
                        if(parseInt(response) > 0) {
                            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', event.id);
                            displayMessage("Deleted Successfully");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }

    });
});

function displayMessage(message) {
    $(".response").html("<div class='success'>"+message+"</div>");
    setInterval(function() { $(".success").fadeOut(); }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Just a thought - can you see the JS in the HTML Source view of the page... just to check it got loaded and can be seen and all that good stuff :)

Comment: @TimBrownlaw Good question. Yes, the JS code is showing up.

Comment: Have you tried putting in some console.log() messages in various places in the JS (which you can view via the development / console on your browser) and see where its "not getting to" that way? That's a good way to see what's going on.

Comment: So I tried putting console.log in the code on the view, but nothing worked. Can you recommend a spot to put one?

Also, I added a dd to the controller. I am able to get to the index function, but it skips the first line that says "if (request()->ajax)) - please see the code in the previous comment.

Comment: Well you put them in places you want to see if the code gets there... I see there is a parsed setting for your SITEURL. is that being correctly set.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still quite the newbie. :)

I discovered that the data isn't being pulled from the database. The index function says "if request ajax" and it's not getting inside that function. So it's saying the request isn't ajax. 

I'm about ready to give up on Fullcalendar. I have been trying different tutorials and searching forever. Any recommendations to try instead?

Comment: I'd recommend going back to the basics...i.e just get the calendar up and running without all the extra bits and work your way back up. You'll figure it out :)

Comment: What I would recommend (if you haven't tried this yet) is to get it running in simple PHP working from the examples and get familiar with it. So dumb it down, and see if you can get it working. I've had to do that before  and it does help.

Comment: That is a really good idea. I will try to set it up as a stand-alone app and see what I can get. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured this out. Thanks to everyone that responded! Once I started a new Laravel project, I was able to pinpoint what I was missing.

It turns out that there were a couple issues:

The first one was that the docs on the Fullcalendar.io website weren't very helpful. It gives you a place to start, but then you are on your own to figure out what's missing in the code. My code needed this added to the script in the view:

```
var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
```

events: '/myurlfeed.php'
});

The second is that the tutorial I followed included an if statement saying that if it was ajax, then execute code. Once I took out the if portion, it directly accessed the code and was able to load from the database. Whew! Lots of hours spent trying to figure this out.

Comment: That's what I like to see :) Glad you got it sorted out.